# Is there a way to format scroll bars in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using Tableau to create dashboards visualising data that often require users to scroll to view the full page. But the scroll bar for the page is thin, grey and difficult to see.

Many of our dashboard users aren't the most technically fluent and are feeding back that they struggle to find/use the scroll bar.

Is there a way to format the scroll bar to make it larger/change it's colour?

Answer (score 1):

Tableau doesn't allow users to change or format the visual scrollbars,
You can embed your dashboard and using CSS you can very well format your scrollbars.

Comment: Ambitious solution :/